# Can't get Macbook Air (2013) and Dell monitor to connect over DisplayPort

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I can connect the Macbook Air to the Dell monitor (P2314H) over VGA with a mini DisplayPort to VGA connector. I would like to get it working over DisplayPort though, as I've read that the picture quality will be better then (digital signal).

When I connect over DisplayPort, using a mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort connector, I see the Macbook screen blink, and the Dell monitor thinks there's something going on too, but not a signal that it can understand. Below is the console log from my computer the moment I connect the two over DisplayPort.

EDIT: I see the monitor (Dell P2314H) uses DisplayPort 1.2a, whereas the Macbook Air only uses DisplayPort 1.1 -- could that be the cause?

Console log:

```
13/10/14 20:48:02,101 WindowServer[96]: Received display connect changed for display 0x42737c0
13/10/14 20:48:02,103 WindowServer[96]: Found 16 modes for display 0x042737c0 [16, 0]
13/10/14 20:48:02,120 WindowServer[96]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
13/10/14 20:48:02,120 WindowServer[96]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
13/10/14 20:48:02,120 WindowServer[96]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
13/10/14 20:48:02,120 WindowServer[96]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
13/10/14 20:48:02,147 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 16 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cdf, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xea8876a9951cb458a16805bc015c42a8, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
13/10/14 20:48:02,147 WindowServer[96]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024500, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
13/10/14 20:48:02,147 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:02,148 WindowServer[96]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024500, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
13/10/14 20:48:02,148 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:02,148 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:02,151 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80002000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
13/10/14 20:48:02,152 WindowServer[96]: Display added
13/10/14 20:48:02,152 WindowServer[96]: Display removed
13/10/14 20:48:02,153 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 16 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cdf, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xea8876a9951cb458a16805bc015c42a8, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
13/10/14 20:48:02,153 WindowServer[96]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024500, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
13/10/14 20:48:02,153 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:02,153 WindowServer[96]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024500, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
13/10/14 20:48:02,153 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:02,153 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:02,184 WindowServer[96]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x042737c0 device: 0x7fb9da407fb0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
13/10/14 20:48:02,000 kernel[0]: USB (XHCI Root Hub USB 2.0 Simulation):Port 1 on bus 0xa connected or disconnected: portSC(0xe0206e1)
13/10/14 20:48:03,822 WindowServer[96]: Received display connect changed for display 0x42737c0
13/10/14 20:48:03,823 WindowServer[96]: Found 16 modes for display 0x042737c0 [16, 0]
13/10/14 20:48:03,840 WindowServer[96]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
13/10/14 20:48:03,840 WindowServer[96]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
13/10/14 20:48:03,840 WindowServer[96]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
13/10/14 20:48:03,841 WindowServer[96]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
13/10/14 20:48:03,924 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 16 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cdf, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xea8876a9951cb458a16805bc015c42a8, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
13/10/14 20:48:03,925 WindowServer[96]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024500, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
13/10/14 20:48:03,925 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:03,925 WindowServer[96]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024500, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
13/10/14 20:48:03,925 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:03,925 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:04,121 WindowServer[96]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
13/10/14 20:48:04,136 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80004000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
13/10/14 20:48:04,137 WindowServer[96]: Display added
13/10/14 20:48:04,137 WindowServer[96]: Display removed
13/10/14 20:48:04,138 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 16 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cdf, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xea8876a9951cb458a16805bc015c42a8, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
13/10/14 20:48:04,138 WindowServer[96]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024500, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
13/10/14 20:48:04,138 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:04,138 WindowServer[96]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024500, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003587, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
13/10/14 20:48:04,138 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:04,138 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
13/10/14 20:48:04,152 WindowServer[96]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
13/10/14 20:48:04,173 WindowServer[96]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x042737c0 device: 0x7fb9da407fb0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
13/10/14 20:48:04,231 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
13/10/14 20:48:04,286 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
13/10/14 20:48:04,301 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
13/10/14 20:48:04,405 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
13/10/14 20:48:05,841 WindowServer[96]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
13/10/14 20:48:05,878 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
13/10/14 20:48:05,908 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
13/10/14 20:48:06,137 WindowServer[96]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
13/10/14 20:48:06,176 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
13/10/14 20:48:06,191 WindowServer[96]: Display 0x042737c0: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
```

Comment: It is trying to run it in a non supported resolution mode. Turn off your video card and try again, if successful turn on the video card and select the supported resolution.

Comment: Could you tell us about the make/model of your "mini DisplayPort to VGA connector"

Answer (score -2):

Open **Display** under **System Preferences**.

Click **Gather Windows**.  That will allow you to see the display settings for the Dell Monitor.

On the "Dell Monitor" display window, Chose **Scaled** and try a different resolution.

Comment: There's no "Gather Windows" button.